# VBscript to telnet a string with variable timestamp

Tags: vbscript, telnet, unix-timestamp, sendkeys

I'm trying to establish a telnet connection to a listening port on a server, and to send various strings of data, one of which should be a unix timestamp. Here is an example of what I've tried to do:

```
Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cloner.run"cmd"
WScript.Sleep 500

cloner.SendKeys"telnet 192.168.1.7 6996"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")

cloner.SendKeys"__BEGIN__"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")

cloner.SendKeys"__1347042718__"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")

cloner.SendKeys"         1     0                 2      0          "
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")

cloner.SendKeys"__END__"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
```

Now that works like a charm, but I would now like to replace the static timestamp (1347042718) in between the __ __ by the result of this:

```
WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now()) - -4 * 3600
```

Additionally, I would like to send a new __ timestamp __string every 30 seconds after the initial set of strings mentionned above. Is there any way to loop a sendkeys command?

I have very little scripting knowledge so the more detail I can get, the better. :)

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can loop `SendKeys()` like any other command.

```
Do
  timestamp = DateDiff("s", #01/01/1970#, Now) + 4 * 3600
  cloner.SendKeys "__" & timestamp & "__"
  cloner.SendKeys "{Enter}"
  WScript.Sleep 30000
Loop While True
```

Comment: Wow Thanks so much! This does exactly what I needed. Although another problem emerged :) I was not aware that a sendkeys command was performed regardless of the active application on my desktop. Therefore, as soon as the telnet window is not active, I have problems. Ideally, I would like to run a script in the background that could run forever seemlessly. Is there a way to do this? Maybe the sendkeys command is not right. A combination of a batch file with some vbscript reference maybe? Thank you for your valuable insight.

Comment: You could use the [`AppActivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29) method to bring the window to the foreground before sending it keystrokes. However, `SendKeys` is a rather unreliable method to begin with. From what I've heard [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) provides a more robust way of automating this kind of task. I've never used it myself, though.